# Right and left margin to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I created the following UITableViewCells and set the background to white.

[image]

(the black frame is the simulator frame).

I would like to add margins right and left to the cell.

I looked in many Q&A and they all suggested customizing the cell with UiImageView. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you using storyboard or native code to create the tableview

Comment: I am using storyboard, but implement the delegates method inside the UIViewController which has a UITableView

Comment: maybe you can try with tableview grouped style

Comment: I changed the style to group style but it didn't add margins

Comment: per margin you mean border as the gray ones in the picture?

Comment: it would be clear - the grey is the background of the view controller. the table is clear as well. I mean to add border right and left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `UIView` as contentView of the cell:

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIView *viewLeft = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, heightOfTheCell)];
viewLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:viewLeft];


UIView *viewRight = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 0, 10, heightOfTheCell)];
viewRight.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:viewRight];
```

and in this way you can have round corners:

```
[cell.layer setCornerRadius: 5];
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f]
CGColorRef colorRed = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
[cell.layer setBorderColor:colorRed];
```

[image]

Comment: My only concern now.. what if I want the cell to have round corners? I won't be able to see them as the view would hide it

Comment: @Dejel I forgot to tell you that for the round corner must add the QuartzCore Framework

Comment: I wanted to add the round corners to the white background, not to the red ones

Comment: @Dejel hello, I have encountered the same problem with you, have you resolved it ? Please

Comment: What if your width is not 320 px anymore? You will need to manually recalculate your width, corner radius and border width accordingly.. Is there a way to do in NSLayoutConstraint or other methods?